# Racket: Settings options on TCP sockets

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, racket

I need to send data over the wire using TCP as a transport layer, and the library `racket/tcp` works fine for this purpose, but I'd like to set some options for the sockets, e. g. `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO`.

I've found this library [vyzo/socket](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=socket.plt&owner=vyzo), but I'm not sure it's the best (and only) option to modify sockets' parameters, since it described as "BSD/POSIX sockets library for mzscheme" on the official site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick grep of the Racket source (for `setsockopt`) suggests that there is no built-in interface that you can use to specify arbitrary socket options (all uses of `setsockopt` that I've found use fixed options only). So, I think what you've got is probably the best option available.